# Sort function in Sunburst graph pyecharts

Tags: python, echarts

I have a Sunburst graph like this:
I want the graph to start monthwise, like August, October and then November. I tried using `sort= undefined` but it does not fix it, even though it works in `echarts`

This is the current option set:

```py
c = (
    Sunburst(init_opts=opts.InitOpts(width="1200px", height="1200px"))
    .add(
        "",
        data_pair=data4,
        highlight_policy="ancestor",
        radius=[0, "95%"],
        sort_="undefined",
    )
      .render("sunburst1.html")
)
```

Does anyone know how could I fix this, I have been looking through the documentation and examples, but there's not any information on this.

Comment: Sunburst plots are designed to be naturally ordered by contribution sizes. Custom ordering should be used with care. Having said that, what is exactly the order you expect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write JS code in `sort_` to use it. There is an issue on [github](https://github.com/pyecharts/pyecharts/issues/1998)   about this. To keep the data default order and not by value, set `sort_ = types.JsCode("null")`

```py
from pyecharts.charts import Sunburst
from pyecharts import options as opts, types

c = (
    Sunburst(init_opts=opts.InitOpts(width="1200px", height="1200px"))
    .add(
        "",
        data_pair=data,
        highlight_policy="ancestor",
        radius=[0, "95%"],
        sort_=types.JsCode("null"),
    )
      .render("sunburst.html")
)
```

After disabling it's default JS sort you can sort `data` in python. For example in your case you want to sort it by months and this is your original data.

```py
data = [
    opts.SunburstItem(
        name="2021",
        children=[
            opts.SunburstItem(
                name="October",
                value=15,
                children=[
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="24th", value=2),
                    opts.SunburstItem(
                        name="7th",
                        value=5,
                        children=[opts.SunburstItem(name="0.1.0", value=2)],
                    ),
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="5th", value=4),
                ],
            ),
            opts.SunburstItem(
                name="August",
                value=10,
                children=[
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="17th", value=5),
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="13th", value=1),
                ],
            ),
            opts.SunburstItem(
                name="November",
                value=10,
                children=[
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="12th", value=5),
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="4th", value=1),
                ],
            ),
        ],
    ),
    opts.SunburstItem(
        name="2022",
        children=[
            opts.SunburstItem(
                name="May",
                children=[
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="16th", value=1),
                    opts.SunburstItem(name="8th", value=2),
                ],
            )
        ],
    ),
]
```

You can sort it this way

```py
from datetime import datetime

for i, year in enumerate(data):
    months = year.opts['children']
    sorted_months = sorted(months, key=lambda m: datetime.strptime(m.opts['name'], "%B"))
    data[i].opts['children'] = sorted_months
```